# Building Android 10 for BeagleBone Black

Tags: beagleboneblack, android-10.0

I have a Beagle_Bone_Black board and I'm wondering if I can install a recent android version on it (Android 10 for example). I have already installed the Android KitKat (4.4.4) and it worked well.

For Android-10, I have downloaded the aosp, but I don't know how or from where I can retrieve the BBB-Android-files to put them under aosp/device/ti (example for Android-444 below) then, be able to do "lunch beaglebone...."

```
~/android_444$ tree device/ti/beagleboneblack/
device/ti/beagleboneblack/
├── 0001-Fix-CallStack-API.patch
├── Android.mk
├── AndroidProducts.mk
├── audio_policy.conf
├── beagleboneblack.mk
├── beagleboneblack.mk~
├── BoardConfig.mk
├── CleanSpec.mk
├── device.mk
├── device.mk~
├── device-sgx.mk
├── fstab.am335xevm
├── gpio-keys.kl
├── init.am335xevm.rc
├── init.am335xevm.usb.rc
├── kernel-patches
│   ├── 0001-Reboot-reason-flags-for-BBB.patch
│   └── 0002-Tweak-backlight-PWM-for-LCD4-Beaglebone-cape.patch
├── liblights
│   ├── Android.mk
│   └── lights.c
├── media_codecs.xml
├── media_profiles.xml
├── mixer_paths.xml
├── overlay
│   └── frameworks
│       └── base
│           ├── core
│           │   └── res
│           │       └── res
│           │           ├── values
│           │           │   └── config.xml
│           │           └── xml
│           │               └── storage_list.xml
│           └── packages
│               └── SettingsProvider
│                   └── res
│                       └── values
│                           └── defaults.xml
├── README.md
├── sgx
├── ti-tsc.idc
├── uEnv.txt
├── ueventd.am335xevm.rc
├── vendorsetup.sh
└── vold.fstab

15 directories, 31 files
```

To get the above BBB specific files i did the following steps:

```
2-  Retrieve the files specific to the platform:

mkdir –p $Workdir/aosp/device/ti
cd $Workdir/aosp/device/ti
git clone https://github.com/csimmonds/bbb-android-device-files.git beagleboneblack
cd $Workdir/aosp/device/ti/beagleboneblack
git checkout kk4.4-sdcard
```

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are several difference between Android 4.4 and Android 10. So, just using the same device folder from Android 4.4 won't work. It's necessary some vendor bring up and port.

But you can you the Android 10 port made by Opersys described below:
https://www.opersys.com/blog/android-10-on-beaglebone-black/

The manifest is avaliable here: https://github.com/opersys/bbb-platform_manifest

Note that some features doesn't work, but it can boot and you can use adb properly.